# Send $http request before initialize routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I have a `$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart")` event that changes **title**, and **description**.
 **And I have to use an `$rootScope` *object* that is created after `$http` request, in my `event`.** Problem is that when the `$stateChangeStart` event runs, my `object` is undefined.

I have tried to use `resolve` on my `ui-router` states. But it only works for the controller, not `event`.

Could you help me to come up with a solution, **that will run my service (with the `$http` request) before routing starts (and `$stateChangeStart` event runs), AND it won't run this service again after state changes.**

Comment: you need to create a provider & run it inside you config phase & store it to provider variable and use that provider variable instead of $rootScope

Comment: Please add a plunker, so we could help ya.

Comment: You cant use $http in a provider. Services are not available when providers run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to try solve this with a `promise`:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

    if ($rootScope.myObj) { // if my "object" was already created
        eventLogic();
    } else {
        getMyObj.init().then(function(res){ //call service that retuns a promise
            eventLogic();
        });
    }

    function eventLogic() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This solution solves my problem entirely. It waits for `$rootScope.myObj` to be created and it runs this service only once.

Comment: Have a look at http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider , specifically the `$urlRouterProvier.deferIntercept()` function.  You can defer routing until you're read by invoking that function.  Then call `$urlRouter.listen()` when ready, and routing will begin.

Comment: $urlRouter.listen() does not reload current state, unfortunately.

Comment: You'll have to add `$urlRouter.sync()` after `$urlRouter.listen()`.